# How does a ListView item gets focused in Xamarin forms UWP?

Tags: xamarin, uwp, focus

Usually in Xamarin forms, only active elements like Button, ImageButton receives the focus but not the passive elements like layouts and label elements. However in case of ListView or CollectionView, the templated items gets focused during key navigation. Any idea how this is feasible? Could someone navigate to the source code usage regarding this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

> How does a ListView item gets focused in Xamarin forms UWP?

The UWP native ListView is allowed `XYFocusKeyboardNavigation` by default, so you could navigation with the keyboard arrow keys. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/focus-navigation) is document that you could refer.

And if you want enable for the control that in the specific panel container, you could enable `XYFocusKeyboardNavigation` like the following in uwp

```
<StackPanel Name="ContainerSecondary"                   
            XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled" 
            TabFocusNavigation ="Cycle"
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="Red" 
            BorderThickness="2"
            Padding="5" Margin="5">
    <Button Name="B2" 
            Content="B2" 
            GettingFocus="Btn_GettingFocus" 
            Margin="5"/>
    <Button Name="B3" 
            Content="B3" 
            GettingFocus="Btn_GettingFocus" 
            Margin="5"/>
    <Button Name="B4" 
            Content="B4" 
            GettingFocus="Btn_GettingFocus" 
            Margin="5"/>
    <Button Name="B5" 
            Content="B5" 
            GettingFocus="Btn_GettingFocus" 
            Margin="5"/>
    <Button Name="B6" 
            Content="B6" 
            GettingFocus="Btn_GettingFocus" 
            Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Unfortunately, Xamarin StackLayout does not contain such property, I have to say you may not implement in forms.